# HTML/CSS Positioning of 3divs

Tags: html, css

I got an issue with my html/css text.
Im very new to coding so it's a very basic question:

my 2 .left blocks of text are supposed to be put on the left side( which works fine).
The right longer block on the other hand is somehow arranging on the right of the second block but realy should be just next to both blocks (so both sides are equally long)    My Css:

My CSS:

```
    body{
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
}
div {
   border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
#header{
    width : 110%;
    height : 40px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: -19px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
#header h2{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: black;
}
.left div {
height: 480px;
width: 48%;
margin-top:40px;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-left:30px;
background-color :white;
float: left;
clear: left;

}

.right {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 48%;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    background-color :white;
    float:right;
}

#footer{
    background-color:white;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom:-30px;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
}
.right p {

    margin-left:20px;
}
a:hover{
    font-weight:bold;
}
#footer a {
    position:relative;
    font-family:Arial;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
#footer p {
    margin-top:10;
    margin-bottom:10;
}
```

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <title>

    </title>
</head>
<body>
        <div id ="header">
        <h2> Meine Website </h2>

        </div>
        <div class ="left">
         <div>
          <ul>
           <li> erster punkt </li>
           <li> zweiter punkt </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         <div>
          <ul> 
            <li> erster punkt2 </li>
            <li> zweiter punkt2 </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class ="right">

        <p> paragraph </p>

        </div>
        <div id ="footer">
         <p> Meine E-mail: 
         <a href= "mailto:mstemmeler@online.de" >mstemmeler@online.de </a> 
</p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What i have is:

```
left1 
left2 right1
      right1
```

what i want is:

```
left1 right1
left2 right1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    border: none;
}
```

and change your style on selector `.left div` to

```
.left div {
    height: 480px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    background-color:white;
    clear: left;
}
```

Try this, is that result you want?

Answer (score 0):

Apply below styling change ,applied float left  to .left container

```
.left{

    float:left;
}
```